# how to ignore number_format_exception error in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Hii how to ignore datatype error in below query since it throws error when a string value is provided for a field that has non-numeric(long) datatype. I am aware of lenient parameter but it does not work with term query.

```
GET employee/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "employee_id": [
                      "abcdef"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "employee_name": [
                      "abcdef"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

Error Message

```
"caused_by": {
            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"abcdef\""
          }
```

Elasticsearch details

```
"version" : {
    "number" : "7.1.1",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "Unknown",
    "build_date" : "2020-11-03T08:48:42.499923Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  }
```

So the expected behaviour is the datatype error should be ignored and the rest of query runs and produces the result since it is in a should condition and if there is a must condition then give no result

mapping of index

```
{
  "employee" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "true",
      "properties" : {
        "employee_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index?

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`query_string_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) instead:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "employee_id:abcdef"   <---
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "employee_name": [
                    "abcdef"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Your original query was a `terms` query which is equivalent to a logical `OR`. As such, you can [adapt the query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) to be:

```sql
"employee_id:(abcdef OR xyz OR 123)"
```

where the value type won't play a role.

Comment: Joe your solution worked perfectly as expected thank you